# How do I create different user registration pages?

Tags: users

In my project, I need to have two types of user: normal user (who can buy products) and merchant user (who can upload products).

I made the registration page by creating the user_register.tpl.php template file.
I don't have any idea about how to make another registration page which will be used for merchant users.

Is there a contributed module available for this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to create only one registration page. And you have to create two roles.
**Normal User and Merchant User**
Add these roles field on user registration page using [Auto Assign Role](http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) module.
Configure permissions for the respective role. Like Normal users can **buy product** and Merchant users can **create product**
If you are using [Commerce Kickstart](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) then you will have permission for adding product and other permissions.

Comment: Thanks Mohit,But i think if I do this, i will have one problem. I need two different registration page to serve my purpose, but i think i can create only one user_register.tpl.

Comment: You will have radio buttons from that you can select respective role. Do you have different fields on registration form for both the roles ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Ubercart Marketplace](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart_marketplace)?  It's especially effective for what you're describing, especially if you're not shipping physical products.